# Is there any way to flee from a boss fight other than death?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I'm fighting a major boss in Diablo III (Maghda, Belial, the Big D himself, and so on), is there any way to escape or flee from the arena other than death? Can I quit the game, or yank my ethernet cable?

Answer (score 12):

This can be used from what I read. In a game by your self, pause the game. Then log in on a different computer. This will cause you to be kicked out of the game.

The other thing that I've noticed if you afk too long (about 25+ mins)  paused you get kicked from the game, so that could be an option as well.

Both methods could be useful for hardcore mode, in normal mode I would just take the death.

Comment: only applies in non-public games.

Comment: Are you sure that the 10 second countdown timer doesn't kick in using this technique?

Comment: @bwarner The first method I only just heard about and have been unable to do any testing on. The second method I know there is no 10 second countdown on it, but I was playing normal. (I doubt it makes a difference)

Comment: The second method can't save you from death. Once I paused and went afk. A few minutes later I came back and saw I was disconnected. Then I re-logged in and found I was dead. I wasn't trying to cheat. I just thought pausing was safe. I didn't know I would get disconnected for pausing too long. It seems that when you get disconnected, you are no longer considered "paused". You are considered active for a number of seconds and monsters can take the time to kill you. Losing a character in that way is irritating. >_<

Comment: Have you ever tried this yourself and can confirm that it works? If so, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @BrQAnt You can no longer log into your account a second time to disconnect you, it was fixed in 1.0.3. I have submitted an edit to the answer to clarify this. I do not believe that idling out will work either but I haven't tested it personally. Betty (comment above) appears to have lost a character while performing these actions though.

Answer (score 10):

If you are outside of town, the only way to quit the game involves a 10 second countdown timer. Whether you yank your ethernet cable, unplug your computer, or just go to menu -> leave game, the countdown timer will be triggered. Your character will stand still and take no actions for 10 seconds as you wait to leave the game. This occurs whether or not you can visibly witness it.

So, yes, you can leave a game during a boss fight. If the reason you want to leave the boss fight is because you want to avoid death, however, I don't think it's going to work out too well. If you're having trouble surviving while actively fighting back, being completely motionless for 10 seconds isn't going to help matters.

Answer (score 3):

Pulling out the internet cable still leaves you in the game for a while before you time out so you would still die. Same for just quiting the game, probably enough to get you killed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do any of the following:

1) Yank the ethernet cable, this terminates communication to and from the server
2) Hard reset your computer (power removal or holding the button)
3) Exit the game (you have to survive about ten seconds or die it doesn't really matter)
4) Log out (same as #3)

There are no ways to get out of the arena, i.e. town portals will not save you.  It should be noted it is still possible to have your character die (which is of concern in hardcore mode)  and to suffer equipment damage.

Comment: That is also what I would like to know.

Comment: @desaiw I did not downvote this but any of these will get you killed. Probably the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @Halfwarr Not necessarily, there is just a high probability fo rit

Comment: @desaivv Please [see here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/why-dont-we-require-a-down-voting-reason). Commenting while downvoting may be helpful occasionally, but it should by no means be mandatory.

Comment: @StrixVaria even still, the downvote occurred seconds after I posted, which implies (to me having been on SE networks for ~2 years) something so grievous that it needed to have a comment.

Comment: @desaivv I just wanted to list a reason why it might be downvoted and put a disclaimer that I personally did not vote it down for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's no efficient way to instantly quit the game, I think. So yes, either you die or you wait 10 seconds for the game to close.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually get someone to tank the boss for you while you quit the game. Just a suggestion.

Comment: then how would they get out?

Comment: @nageeb: obviously they ask someone else to tank the boss!